# Configuring the AD FS Identifier so that it matches the AD FS token issuer

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, adfs, windows-server-2016

I'm in a complete brain fart and I feel as though my eyes are going to pop out of my head troubleshooting ADFS. I am trying to set ADFS Identifier so that it matches the token issuer. If I do `Get-AdfsProperties` in PowerShell it works very well. The problem comes when I want to set the `-Identifier` to match the token issuer. Its giving a weird error. Below is my PowerShell script and results.

`PS C:\Windows\system32>$adfsProperties = Get-AdfsProperties`
`PS C:\Windows\system32>Set-AdfsProperties -Identifier $adfsProperties.IdTokenIssuer`
`Set-AdfsProperties : Cannot validate the argument on parameter 'Identifier'. The argument is null.` `Provide a valid value for the argument, then try running the command again.`
`At line: 1 cahr: 32`
`+Set-AdfsProperties -Identifier $adfsProperties.IdTokenIssuer`
`+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
`+ CategoryInfo          :InvalidData: (:) [Set-AdfsProperties], ParameterBindingException`
`+FullyQualifiedErrorId  :PositionalParameterNotFound, Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.COmmands.SetServicePropertiesCommand`

Any help please!!

Answer (score 0):

PS C:\Users\administrator.XXXXXXXX> Set-AdfsProperties -IdTokenIssuer https://adfs.XXXXXXXXX.nl/adfs

Modifying the ID token issuer will invalidate previously issued id tokens and previously configured trusts.
Additionally, the OpenID Connect Discovery doc will be served from the following new location:
'/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Make sure you have updated any clients, native applications, and server
applications before making this change.
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
WARNING: PS0038: This action requires a restart of the AD FS Windows Service. If you have deployed a federation server
farm, restart the service on every server in the farm.